# Using docker commands failed in virtual environment

Tags: docker, virtualenv

I'm using ubuntu xenial installed docker. I've then created virtual environment for my python project, but the docker commands failed to run. the errors are:

running `docker info`

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

running `docker docker build -t dockerhub.domain.com .`

```
ERRO[0000] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied 
context canceled
```

it don't want to run these commands with sudo, as I have added my user to docker. I can run docker commands outside of the virtual env, but it fails in the environment. any help?

---

edit:

creating venv is done by:

```
conda create --name myenv
```

and I've added my user this way:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

output of `id -nG` (my_user is my username)

```
my_user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Comment: Please share the exact scenario, covering (a) how do you create and enter your venv; (b) a proof that you are able to use Docker without `sudo` outside your venv (because this could be just a matter of your user being not in the `docker` group, which is not a virtualenv-related issue).

Comment: @DanilaKiver thanks for the questions. I've added my answers as new edits in the question. (b) is also tested using ```docker info``` command and it outputs my docker and system info, that shows it works well.

Comment: That `id` command indicates you aren't in the `docker` group.  Did you log out and log in again after running `usermod`?

Comment: @DavidMaze, No. All commands ran in one session.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I think you solved the problem! Now I tried again, and I found the ```docker``` group added at the end of groups, executing ```id -nG``` command. logging out was required for taking effect.

Comment: but i don't know why I could run ```docker``` without ```sudo``` when execuing the ```usermod```, if logging out was required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `usermod` command, only takes effect if you log out and log in (or alternatively using `source` command)

After that, the `id -nG` prints these groups: (my_user is my username)

```
my_user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

and every thing works just fine.